# Unable to find standard report type "Opportunity History" in reports

Tags: reporting, custom-reports, opportunity-history

I am the admin for my salesforce org. During report creation, I can't to view the "Opportunity History" report in the report type lists on my report type selection screen. (Refer below image)

[image]

Based on the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.opp_history.htm&type=5) this "Opportunity History" object available in the orgs which created Summer'09 release and after. My org also created after Summer'09 release.

So May I know, Is there any specific settings need to enabled/ Raise a support case to Salesforce to enable this report type in Salesforce org?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the view & worked for help. Just now find someone from my org is previously **Hide** the `Opportunity History` report by using the [Report hide](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_hide_report_types.htm&type=5) function in report type selection page. Now I have enabled the report type and it's available for view.

Thanks.